# CS0103 and CS0136 with pattern matching

Tags: c#, scope, c#-7.0

I'm a little bit confused. Why from one side I become `CS0103`(variable does not exist) and from another side `CS0136`(with own words - variable already exists) and declaration of variables with same names in switch works?

This **works**:

```
var obj = new object();
switch (obj)
{
    case string str:
        break;

    case object str:
        break;
}
```

Here I become compilation error **CS0103** "The name ' ' does not exist in the current context":

```
var obj = new object();
switch (obj)
{
    case string str: 
        break;
}
if (str == null) { } //CS0103
```

Here I become compilation error **CS0136**:

```
var obj = new object();
switch (obj)
{
    case string str: //<--- CS0136
        break;
}
string str = "";
```

[CS0136: A local variable named 'var' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'var', which is already used in a 'parent or current/child' scope to denote something else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0136)

[CS0103: The name 'identifier' does not exist in the current context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0103)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it sounds like the context is relevant here, particularly given CS0136.

Comment: While the two instances of `str` are not visible outside the `switch` (that's the `cs0103`), it is not legal to declare another `str` either, to prevent programmer confusion (that's the `cs0136`). It *is* legal if you explicitly introduce a new scope (`{ string str = ""; }`). It could be considered inconsistent that multiple different `str` declarations are allowed inside the `switch`, but in this case the risk of confusing them is minimal, since the blocks are lexically separate.

Comment: @JonSkeet The context isn't relevant, it's just theory (by coding noted, that become errors, but it's not a problem). The question corresponds to mCve.

Comment: It's at least confusing. It would be easier to help if you'd provided complete code (ready to be copy/paste/compiled) for each of the error cases. I see what you mean now, but the whole "commented in" part is really confusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, I'll modify question

Comment: Definitely better. I've given an answer which doesn't involve pattern matching, to make it clear that you could have observed it in C# 1.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you for yor comment, but with part of them I'm not agree: _"declarations are allowed inside the switch, but in this case the risk of confusing them is minimal, since the blocks are lexically separate"_, but If we declare the variables with same names in different `case`s we become the error `CS0128` Or have I misunderstood you?

Comment: A local variable inside a `switch` block can be anywhere -- possible buried somewhere deep in the block. The variable used for pattern matching can only be part of the `case`. We might even consider the fact that we can use the same name a feature, since we're really talking about "the same" object treated as a different type. (I don't necessarily agree and I probably would not do this in my own code, but at the very least it's easy to see what block refers to which declaration.) Note that, again, if you give the `case` blocks their own scope (`case ..: {}`), there is no clash.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In real life I wouldn't also give same names to the variables. As I wrote to the Jon Skeet - it's just theory.

Comment: Consider how you might write this without pattern matching: `if (obj is string) { string str = (string) obj; ... } else if (obj is object) { object str = (object) obj; ... }`. If you view the `case` as a translation of that, allowing the same identifier in every case is a little more defensible -- it allows for easier refactoring. Otherwise, an artificial renaming would be necessary and the two approaches could no longer be easily interchanged.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm afraid, that we can't see switch-case as pure translation of if-else. This compiles: `var x=2; if (x==1) { var i = 0; } else { var i = 0; }` and this doesn't: `var x=2; switch(x){ case 1: var i=0; break; case 2: var i=0; break;}`

Comment: You're going the wrong way -- consider how the if-else for pattern matching specifically would be translated to a switch. Obviously the `if` and `else` blocks would get their own scopes, as they currently already do. The fact that you can also write switches where the blocks don't have their own scopes is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three rules at play here:

- The scope of a local variable is normally the entire block in which it's declared. The variables introduced via pattern matching in switch statements are slightly narrower than that, which is how you're able to have patterns of both `object str` and `string str` - but you don't need that to demonstrate these specific errors.
- You can't use a variable outside its scope
- You can't declare one local variable in the scope of another with the same name.

You don't need pattern matching to demonstrate this. Here's a simple method which gives the CS0103 error:

```
void Method()
{
    {
        // Scope of str is the nested block.
        string str = "";
    }
    // str isn't in scope here, so you can't refer to it;
    // second bullet point
    if (str == "") {}
}
```

And here's an example of CS0136:

```
void Method()
{
    {
        // Can't declare this variable, because the str variable
        // declared later is already in scope
        string str = "";
    }
    // Scope of this variable is the whole method
    string str = "";
}
```

Comment: So from your answer - my scopes were whole method and switch, right?

Comment: @Rekshino: Nearly. In fact, the scope of pattern matches in switch statements is smaller, which is why you're allowed to have both `object str` and `string str`. Thanks for the reminder - I'll edit my first bullet point. That's another thing that makes this better to show without pattern matching.

Comment: I suppose misunderstanding comes from implying scope goes downward (not whole method)

Comment: @Rekshino: That explains the second error. The first error is a matter of the variable going out of scope.